# Accessing subclasses across python files

Tags: python, oop

This is my code:

```
@classmethod
def get_all_on_methods(cls):
    results = []
    print(cls.__subclasses__())
    def all_subclasses(cls):
        return set(cls.__subclasses__()).union([s for c in cls.__subclasses__() for s in all_subclasses(c)])

    set_of_classes = all_subclasses(cls)
    print(set_of_classes)

    for klass in set_of_classes:
        for name, attribute in vars(klass).items():
            if name.startswith("on_"):
                results.append((attribute, klass))
    return results

print(DialogModule.get_all_on_methods())
```

The recursive accessing of subclasses works on my own created class hierarchy such as:

```
class Foo(Ur):
   def on_index(self):
      pass
   def some_method(self):
      pass

class Bar(Ur):
   def on_spiking_intent(self):
      pass
   def another_method(self):
      pass
class sub_Bar(Bar):
   def on_vibin(self):
      pass
   def just_vibin(self):
      pass
```

But it does not work when I apply it on the subclasses of the dialog_module which are in different python files but do inherit the dialogue_module class. The simple method **subclasses**() returns nothing ie. no classes which inherit dialogue_module.
Is there some block to getting subclasses from different python files?

How I inherit in different file:

```
YesNoConfirmation(DialogModule):

   alternatives = Entities

   def __init__(self, parent: DialogModule, question: Union[Variants, str], yes_alternatives: list = None,
             no_alternatives: list = None, prompt_yes_acknowledgment: Variants = None,
             prompt_no_acknowledgment: Variants = None, acknowledge: bool = True,
             number_of_retries: int = 2, prompt_no_match: Variants = None,
             prompt_fallback: Variants = None, use_only_regex: bool = False, module_name: str = None
             ):
       super().__init__(parent)
       self._prompts: Prompts = self.get_prompts()
       self._regex_expressions: RegexExpressions = self.get_regex_expressions()
```

Comment: Where the classes are defined shouldn't matter. Are you sure that the other module is actually imported somewhere in the Python process?

Comment: yes they seem to do:
class YesNoConfirmation(DialogModule):
  
   

    def __init__(self, parent: DialogModule, question: Union[Variants, str], yes_alternatives: list = None,
                 no_alternatives: list = None, prompt_yes_acknowledgment: Variants = None,
                 prompt_no_acknowledgment: Variants = None, acknowledge: bool = True,
                 number_of_retries: int = 2, prompt_no_match: Variants = None,
                 prompt_fallback: Variants = None, use_only_regex: bool = False, module_name: str = None
                 ):
        super().__init__(parent)

Comment: Not sure what that is supposed to show, for starters, edit your question and post that there, that really isn't intelligible as a comment.